# why can the extractAllNodesThatMatch function of htmlparser only be used once?

Tags: java, html-parser

i use the htmlparser to parse the web data of book in library.
the code snapet as below

```
NodeList nodes=parser.extractAllNodesThatMatch(filter);
for(int i = 0;i < nodes.size();i++)
{
    Bookinfo cur_bki=new Bookinfo();
    Parser getboolinfo=new Parser(nodes.elementAt(i).toHtml());
    String doc_type=getboolinfo.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new NodeFilter() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(Node node)
                    {
                        return ((node instanceof Tag)
                                && !((Tag)node).isEndTag()
                                && ((Tag)node).getTagName().equals("SPAN")
                                && ((Tag)node).getAttribute("class") != null
                                && ((Tag)node).getAttribute("class").equals());
                    }
                }).elementAt(0).toPlainTextString();
    message("extract doc_type"+doc_type);
    cur_bki.set_doc_type(doc_type);
    getboolinfo=new Parser(nodes.elementAt(i).toHtml());

    TagNameFilter filtertemp=new TagNameFilter("a");
    NodeList tempp = getboolinfo.extractAllNodesThatMatch(filtertemp);
    String title=getboolinfo.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new NodeFilter() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean accept(Node node)
                    {
                        return ((node instanceof Tag)
                                && !((Tag)node).isEndTag()
                                && ((Tag)node).getTagName().equals("A"));
                    }
                }).elementAt(0).toPlainTextString();
    message("extract title"+title);
}
```

if i delete the

```
getboolinfo=new Parser(nodes.elementAt(i).toHtml());
```

then the title will be null
it means i can  use extractAllnodesthatmatch function for only once
but why,can you help me ?

Comment: Have you tried to call setInputHTML(String inputHTML) instead of creating a new parser?

Comment: you mean when i use the parser first time ,i try setInputHTML(String inputHTML) ????

Comment: The second time or maybe create a non-arg parser and call setInputHTML() each time you use it. Just a guess though.

Comment: but what the difference ,,?_?,what i wonder is why shoudl i change the paresr if i parser the same content always....?

Comment: Looks like each HTML String has an associated Lexer instance. So you need to initialize a new Lexer with every new HTML string